# ProviderName for Sql Server .SDF file to use in app.config

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've created a DB file in a project `Add -> New Item -> Local Database` and created a table for it.

Now I would like to create a connection string for it in `app.config`.

The problem is that all example code that I find uses code only to create a connection, and not app.config. Hence I can't figure out which `providerName` I should use.

So what is it?

```
<add name="DemoDb" providerName="XXXXXX" connectionString="Data Source=ExampleDb.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;"/>
```

Comment: It Would be: Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.VersionNumber. Creating local database will create the compact database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`System.Data.SqlServerCE.4.0` or `System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5` depending framework version

Comment: +1. for details see sqlce-tutorial http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2011/06/07/walkthrough-deploy-a-web-application-with-sql-ce-4-0-database-to-iis-host-with-sql-server.aspx